# SQL Query Unique Equipment List

Tags: sql

Thanks in advance for having a look. I have no idea on how to search for this.
Picture 2 test stations, each with a rack of equipment that must be kept calibrated. The equipment is identified by stationId, eqPartno, and eqLocation. Location instead of serial number so it is unit replaceable.

From 2 tables:

station_events (eventId is auto, recUpdated is auto)

```
"stationEventId","stationId","stationEvent","recUpdated"
1,"1","databaseCreation",2014-05-14 07:51:25 AM
2,"55","databaseCreation",2014-05-14 07:51:25 AM
3,"1","updateCal",2014-05-14 08:11:26 AM
4,"1","updateCal",2014-05-14 08:11:59 AM
5,"1","updateCal",2014-05-14 08:48:26 AM
```

equipment (equipmentId is auto, recUpdated is auto, linked by equipmentId)

```
"equipmentId","stationEventId","eqPartNo","eqLocation","eqCalExpires","eqRecUpdated"
1,1,"eq1","loc1",2000-01-31,2014-05-14 07:53:59 AM
2,1,"eq2","loc2",2000-02-22,2014-05-14 08:05:52 AM
3,3,"eq1","loc1",2014-04-04,2014-05-14 08:13:37 AM
4,4,"eq2","loc2",2014-04-05,2014-05-14 08:14:25 AM
5,5,"eq1","loc1",2014-04-05,2014-05-14 08:47:04 AM
```

The query is to form a view of station 1 equipment consisting of the latest record for each of the installed units to verify cal.

```
select e.* from equipment e
inner join station_events se on se.stationEventId=e.stationEventId
where se.stationId='1'
group by eqPartNo,eqLocation
```

The results look good.

```
"equipmentId","stationEventId","eqPartNo","eqLocation","eqCalExpires","eqRecUpdated"
5,5,"eq1","loc1",2014-04-05,2014-05-14 08:47:04 AM
4,4,"eq2","loc2",2014-04-05,2014-05-14 08:14:25 AM
```

Have I just created a lucky hack, or is this correct? I like this because we have calibration history as long as the view is guaranteed to describe all the latest equipment records.

Best Regards,
Jim Shedden

Comment: hm, seems lucky to me, since you use `group by` but no ordering or explicit aggregation (i.e. `MIN` or `MAX` on the relevant columns)

Comment: Hi Jim, this is just a tip. Don't use e.* in your query. If you were to add a column to the equipment table in the future it would break this query as the new field would not be in the group by. Cheers

Comment: Thanks Bobby, I agree I should be more specific. I don't quite understand  why a new field would break anything though. There are already fields in the results that are not in the group by, so I'm not sure I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is lucky one. You may insert an aggregate such MAX into your query

```
select e.equipmentId, 
       e.stationEventId, 
       e.eqPartNo, 
       e.eqLocation, 
       e.eqCalExpires, 
       MAX(e.eqRecUpdated) from equipment e
inner join station_events se on se.stationEventId=e.stationEventId
where se.stationId='1'
group by eqPartNo,eqLocation
```

Comment: Thanks Guillaume,DrCopyPaste. I knew something didn't have the right feel to it. Regards, Jim Shedden